# dealing with tuple of list with flexible size in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell, this question may be very stupid, but sorry I don't know its answer

I have a function that take a 4-tuple of list, size of these lists could be different, But in the tuple they have the same size

```
foo ([a],[b],[c],[d]) = concat [[a],[b])
```

it does not work for the list larger that size one
for example

```
foo ([1],[2],[3],[4]) // works fine 
foo ([1,2] , [2,3] , [3,4] , [5,7]) or any larger size of those list generate error
```

any hint  about to generalize it ?

Comment: `foo ([1,2] , [2,3] , [3,4] , [5,7])` ― what result do you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

Much as the source code text `[1]` means a list with a single element which is the value `1`, the source code text `[a]` means a list with a single element which is the variable `a`<sup>1</sup>. It does *not* mean a list of any size, and `a` refers to the single element of the list, not the list.

On the left hand side of an equation, `[a]` would be a pattern that only matches lists containing precisely one element (not zero, and not 2 or 3 or more); the value of that single element can be referred to by `a` on the right hand side of the equation.

So this code:

```
foo ([a],[b],[c],[d]) = concat [[a],[b]]
```

Gives a definition for the result of applying `foo` to a tuple of 4 singleton lists. It takes the single element in the first two lists (`a` and `b`), wraps those up in new singleton lists (`[a]` and `[b]`), puts those two lists in another list to make a list of lists (`[[a],[b]]`), and then passes that list to a function (`concat [[a],[b]]`).

If any one of the lists has more than one element, or is empty, then this equation doesn't say what the result of `foo` is. And if there are no other equations helping to define the function `foo`, then you'll get a pattern match error if you call `foo` on such non-conforming input.

If (as I suspect) what you wanted was to say that this definition applies to to a tuple of *any* 4 lists, then you would write it this way:

```
foo (a,b,c,d) = concat [a,b]
```

Note the lack of square brackets around `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. This version takes the *entirety* of the first two lists (`a` and `b`), puts those in another list to make a list of lists (`[a,b]`), and then passes that list to a function (`concat [a,b]`).

The *type* of the function (whether inferred from your code or declared by you) says that the things in the tuple that `foo` receives as argument are lists<sup>2</sup>; you don't have to put square brackets around every variable that is a list - indeed you can't, because that means something else quite specific! When you want to match against any possible list, you just write `a`; writing `[a]` says the list has to be a list of exactly one element, and it's only that element which is freely matched by the variable `a`, not the list itself.

Any time you use the square bracket syntax you are writing a list with a fixed number of elements,<sup>3</sup> and the things in the brackets are individual elements of the list.

---

<sup>1</sup> In a context where `[a]` is a value expression. If this occurs in a type expression then `[a]` is the *type* of lists whose elements are the *type* `a`.

<sup>2</sup> Technically if you're using inferred types here then there's nothing at all constraining the types of `c` and `d` in my suggested version because they are unused, so they don't have to be lists.

<sup>3</sup> Unless you're writing a list comprehension (e.g. `[x + 1 | x <- [1, 2, 3]]`) or a numeric range expression (e.g. `[1..n]`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foo (a:_,b:_,c:_,d:_)= concat [[a],[b]]
```

In the above function you just pattern match the first element of the parameters of each list.

A much simpler code:

```
foo (a:_,b:_,_,_)= [a, b]
```

In ghci:

```
ghci> foo ([1],[2],[3],[4])
[1,2]
ghci> foo ([1,2] , [2,3] , [3,4] , [5,7])
[1,2]
```